# How to disable Cell Drag and Drop for a specific workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where users input information into column A that is used in formulas in column B. B1 uses the information in A1, B2 uses in the information in A2, etc.

The sheet is "protected" to only allow users to select and change unlocked cells in column A. They should not be able to change the formatting or structure of the sheet. However, even when the sheet is protected, they are able to "move" cell contents by clicking on the frame of cell and dragging it onto another cell.

If they move A1 onto A2, B1 is now using the information in A2, and B2 gives a reference error.

I would like that, when a user "moves" a cell, a macro is fired that will undo the move.

How can I programmatically detect when a cell is moved or is there a different solution?

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem with the answer posted below?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know of a way to detect when a cell is moved programmatically, or have a different solution to my issue? Other than Microsoft not overlooking this issue with sheet protection :D

I have another solution.

Disable the drag-and-drop functionality in this workbook.  The tricky part is that this is an Application-level setting, so you need to toggle it Enabled/Disabled based on which workbook is Active.

This is not exactly *beginner* level VBA but I have documented it in [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320840/excel-2010-vba-event-handler-for-switching-between-applications/25370317#25370317) and provided a link to an XLSM file containing all of the sample code & modules.

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old post, but I came across it looking for the same thing so I'm sharing an alternate way to address this that I subsequently came up with.

Use the `OFFSET` function to reference the cells in your formula so that you don't have to worry about the drag-and-drop moving the referenced cells.  In the example, B1 references the value in A1, so in B1 use `OFFSET(B1,0,-1)` to reference A1.