# Application.Calculation depending on workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm managing a workbook with more than 200 000 formulas (some really complicated array formulas) which means that I can't let Excel automatically calculate all the cells every time I click somewhere (it takes around 8 hours to calculate everything).

Instead of that, the calculation is set to manual and I have the following VBA code executed when *Calculation.xlsm* is opened:

```
With Application
    .CalculateBeforeSave = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
```

I use custom buttons to calculate only some parts of the 200k cells when needed.

I noticed that Excel does keep track of that setting in each workbooks, which means that if I open my Calculation.xlsm, Excel remembers that the calculation is set to manual. If I open my Values.xlsx, Excel does remember that the calculation is set to automatic. This was before I tried to copy values from *Calculation.xlsm* to *Values.xlsx*.

Now, because I'm using VBA in Calculation.xlsm to copy values to Values.xlsx, Excel does apply the `Application.Calculation` setting to that workbook too, which means that if I open it with a new instance of Excel, the calculation will still be set to manually.

If I add a `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` before closing the *Values.xlsx* with VBA in my *Calculation.xlsm* workbook, it will work, but Excel will also start to compute the 200k cells in my *Calculation.xlsm* workbook, which I obviously don't want.

So my question is about how to actually set the calculation of Excel based on a specific workbook instead of with the `Application` object. This is based on the fact that Excel does keep track of that setting depending on which workbook is opened (you can just do the test and create 2 different *.xlsx* files, one with the calculation enabled and the other with the calculation disabled and Excel will remember these settings).

I know I could use the `Worksheets.Range.Calculate` method to calculate my Values.xlsx workbook before closing it, but the calculation will still be set to manual if I open it in a new instance of Excel after that.

---

**EDIT 3:20pm**: Not sure if I was clear enough, English isn't my native language. In short, I have *Calculation.xlsm* with VBA and `Calculation` set to manual. I have *Values.xlsx* with no VBA and Calculation set to automatic. If I open *Values.xlsx* with the following VBA code in *Calculation.xlsm*, Excel will automatically convert my *Values.xlsx* workbook to manual calculations.

*Calculation.xlsm* code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Application
        .CalculateBeforeSave = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
End Sub

Sub someFunction()
    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open("Values.xlsx")
    Set WBws = WB.Sheets("mySheet")
    DoEvents
    wb.Save
    WB.Close
End Sub
```

After the execution of someFunction(), *Values.xlsx* calculation is set to manual. That's the problem. I would like it to stay on automatic (and I can't add VBA to that file, it must be all done from *Calculation.xlsm* like above).

---

**EDIT 3:40pm**: Could I just have my big workbook with Application.Calculation set to manual, put all the data I need in the clipboard (I only need the values, not the formulas), close it (will the VBA still continue to execute even if I close the workbook from which it is executed?), set Application.Calculation to Auto (since there is no open workbook), then open the destination workbook to paste the values (will Excel still keep the data in the clipboard since the other workbook is closed?), then save and close that workbook, set back the calculation to manual (no workbook opened) and reopen the original workbook from which the code was executed?

Comment: will on open workbook event help you?
like Private Sub Workbook_Open() and add your code whether you want to activate or disable the auto calculation..

Comment: @mehow it means you start the process finish your shift and come back next day :D

Comment: Ya exactly krish KM, that's exactly what it means! I edited my OP just to be sure that you understand.

Comment: Yes. Calculation is an `Application`-level property, so when you set it for one workbook, it applies to all workbooks in that instance of the application.  What you need is maybe an application-level event handler, so that whenever you change the ActiveWorkbook, it resets that property appropriately.

Comment: To that end, you can probably modify the answer I gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320840/excel-2010-vba-event-handler-for-switching-between-applications/25370317#25370317) to toggle the `Application.Calculation` instead of `Application.CelldragAndDrop` property :)

Comment: Or could I use a *buffer* workbook? Taking all the values from the big workbook, copying it in a new workbook, then close the big workbook, set calculation to automatic (I'm just copying the values, no formulas), open the workbook with automatic calculation to copy the values, close it and then open back my big workbook with calculation set to manual before? Or I can just copy the data, keep it in the clipboard, close the original workbook, set calc to auto, open the other workbook and add the values, close it, put back calc to manual and reopen the original workbook.

Comment: Sure, there's more than one way to skin a cat, as they say. You could deal with all that other overhead, or you could store the values from the sheet(s) in Array variables, etc.... But I've already provided one answer for you. You just need to make a few minor changes to that :)

Comment: All right, thank you, I will give a look at that. I provided a second edition to my OP, I was just worrying about if the code would still be executed if I close the workbook from which it is launched.

Comment: you can use a normal `Workbook_BeforeClose` handler to address that potential concern. I mention that in my answer below, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a new instance of Excel.  While this is probably slower, and might be more difficult to work with in cases where you don't close the book/application within the function, but for simple case like your example, it may be easiest to implement:

```
Sub someFunction()
Dim newExcel as Excel.Application
Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Set WB = newExcel.Workbooks.Open("Values.xlsx")
    Set WBws = WB.Sheets("mySheet")
    DoEvents
    wb.Save
    WB.Close
    newExcel.Quit
    Set newExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

The `Application.Calculation` property is relative to that *instance* of the application, not other instances.

**Alternatively**, you can use an application-level event handler. I suspect this might be faster but I have not tested it for speed.

Modified slightly from [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320840/excel-2010-vba-event-handler-for-switching-between-applications/25370317#25370317) (which also asks about conditionally disabling an Application-level property).

If:

> I was just worrying about if the code would still be executed if I close the workbook from which it is launched

Then just use the normal `Workbook_BeforeClose` event handler to restore the desired `Application.Calculation` property (for the entire application/all other open workbooks).

The rest of the answer:

Create an application-level event handler, create a class module named `cEventClass` and put this code in it:

```
Public WithEvents appevent As Application
Dim ret
Private Sub appevent_WorkbookActivate(ByVal wb As Workbook)

    Call ToggleCalculation(wb, ret)
    
End Sub
```

Use the following in a standard module named `mod_Caclulate`:

```
Option Explicit
Public XLEvents As New cEventClass
Sub SetEventHandler()

If XLEvents.appevent Is Nothing Then
    Set XLEvents.appevent = Application
End If

End Sub

Sub ToggleCalculation(wb As Workbook, Optional ret)
    If wb.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        ret = xlCalculationManual
    Else
        ret = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
    Application.Calculation = ret
End Sub
```

Put this in the `Workbook_Open` event handler of the workbook which you always want to be *manual* calculation:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Create the event handler when the workbook opens
    Call mod_Caclulate.SetEventHandler
    Call mod_Caclulate.ToggleCalculation(Me)

End Sub
```

This will create the event handler only when the specific workbook is opened, and the handler will toggle the `Calculation` property whenever you switch views to a different workbook.

**Note:** If you "end" run-time or do anything while debugging which would cause state loss, you will lose the event handler. This can always be restored by calling the Workbook_Open procedure, so an additional safeguard might be to add this also in the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
' Additional safeguard in case state loss has killed the event handler:
' use some workbook-level events to re-instantiate the event handler

    Call Workbook_Open
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to just create a new Application object with VBA? Wouldn't that be easier? If I can have 2 separate Application objects and copy data from a workbook in the first App object to a workbook to the other App object which both have different App.Calculation values. If it's not possible, I will go with the event handler, altough I'm a little bit reluctant to use events (I had bad performance issues with VBA and events in Outlook).

Comment: Sure you could do that. Let me amend my answer to include that option.

Comment: The alternative solution works flawlessly, I have no idea why I didn't think of it before. However, your first original solution is more robust if I ever need to open more than 2 workbooks.

Comment: You can have more than 2 instances of Excel if needed :)